# Recompile AngularJS nested directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to manually recompile a directive nested inside another directive?

I have a `modal-create-task` directive that is initialized using a `showCreateTaskModal` event together with some data. Based on the data coming with the event the modal change its UI layout and also changes the behavior of a nested directive called `search-projects`.

The problem I'm having at the moment is that I need to recompile the `search-directive` because it needs the data coming in with `showCreateTaskModal` is fired.

This is how the modal template looks like:

```
<div class="ui modal" id="modalCreateTask" ng-controller="ModalCreateTaskCtrl">

    <search-projects oo-filter="{{ mode }}" oo-subject="searchProjectSubject"></search-projects>

</div>
```

As you can see both the `oo-filter` and `oo-subject` attributes are depending on the data attached to the `showCreateTaskModal` event, but that event is fired only after the compiler goes through the DOM and then the directive has no access to the needed data, so it falls back to default behavior.

This is the `search-projects` definition:

```
angular.module('app.ui.search.projects').directive('searchProjects', function(ConfigService)
{
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        templateUrl : ConfigService.path.views + '/search/projects.html',
        scope : {
            filter : '@ooFilter',
            subject : '=ooSubject'
        }
    }
});
```

Edit 1:

As per request I'll try to explain better what I'm doing.

I have a modal that contains another directive that, based on the content of certain variables, should query the server for data whenever the attributes are changing.

I wanted to recompile the directive in order to execute the `init()` function again.

Making some researches I also noticed that it's possible to use `$watch` but I don't know if that's a good solution.

Comment: There are ways to recompile, but it is almost never needed. Can you explain in more detail (perhaps with an illustrative example) what you are trying to achieve? What data is available and when. Why can't the data itself be regenerated?

Comment: @NewDev I added more information to my question so now it should be clearer.

Comment: You can definitely use `$watch` to react to change in data. Better than recompiling, for sure

Comment: Good, then I'll change my strategy in favor of `$watch`. If you want, write down the answer and I'll mark and upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite rare that a directive requires recompiling. This could be indicative of a wrong approach or design.

Directives react to data. Typically, data is passed to a directive via attributes, or broadcasted events, or a shared service with the controller. Specifically, isolate scope uses one- and two- way data binding to pass data to the directive.

In absence of a different trigger, one could `$watch` for changes:

```
link: function(scope){
   scope.$watch("scopeVar", function(){
     // do something, like run init() again
   });
}
```

Another alternative is via direct trigger from a service, similar to how [Angular-UI $modal](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) service works. The modal instance exposes a method, for example, to close the modal (directive) from the controller:

```
modalInstance.close(result);
```

This idea *could* be similarly used to trigger some actions in the directive that uses the same service.

Answer (score 1):

Attach an 'ng-if' condition to your 'search-projects' directive based on the data that is coming from your event. So your code might look like this :

```
<div class="ui modal" id="modalCreateTask" ng-controller="ModalCreateTaskCtrl">

    <search-projects oo-filter="{{ mode }}" oo-subject="searchProjectSubject"
      ng-if="dataComingFromEvent"></search-projects>

</div>
```

The directive will be put again in the DOM when the data is available in the 'model' viz 'dataComingFromEvent' and hence your directive will be recompiled.

Comment: Sorry, your solution partially works. The directive is recompiled only if the attributes are not set and then set again. If the value of the attributes is changes then the element is not recompiled.